# Laravel 5.7.6 Email Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.7

I recently Installed the latest version of Laravel & used the docs to create Email Verification that comes out of the box with laravel according to this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification however, when I receive the email and click on it I face with a `403 forbidden` page.

I have searched the web and did not find an answer to this problem. Please let me know if you need more information to help me with the issue.

**Note**:
My problem is not related to https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/25723. I have checked the links & the generated tokens & they are fine.

Comment: More information would be helpful. Are you testing this locally, or on a live server? Does the link direct you to an https:// page? If so, do you have SSL properly configured on your server?

Comment: I am testing it on a live server. the SSL is configured as well & no issue in that regard. If i disable email verification all the routes and controllers work as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turned out to be my configuration. I was using nginx as reverse proxy for my apache website (laravel application) & after investigating more I found out that all the signatures were failing on the website (not only email verification but even signed routes)

So currently I am using nginx + php-fpm . I hope it helps anyone who faces the similar configuration.

**If you know a way to go around this issue (using reverse-proxy), please comment! Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to the problem by reordering the middleware links as follows:

```
'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your comment! it is related but this is was not the problem. I am going to answer my own question because I just found out what the issue is!